# Issue in creating sites with different regional setting

Tags: development, 2013

I am using SharePoint 2013 Standard edition(June CU update) and facing an issue with multi-lingual sites.

I have custom web templates with which sites are created. The current template which I am using in inheriting from Team site template.

However, when I create a site with a different locale I am encountering java-script errors which is manifesting as different errors. A few errors I can list are

- Not able to delete a web-part on the home page
- The task list is not editable

The js error is specifically coming in sp.ui.timeline.js (_spRegionalSettings undefined). I have attached the snapshot below

[image]

On changing the region in regional settings everything works fine.

To confirm this issue is not with my custom web template I have tried the same thing on OOB Team site template. I created a Swedish language site and also changed my browser language to Swedish. Still the same error persists.

I have attached my regional settings for reference.

[image]

Is this a bug in SharePoint or does anybody have a workaround for this?

Comment: have you installed the Swedish language pack for sharepoint 2013?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the Swedish language pack and enabled it on web. As I mentioned the issue is same when I create team site with Swedish locale from SharePoint central admin

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out this issue. The issue was happening when the TimeZone was different from the Locale (its still wierd and hard to explain). Once I changed the timezone and locale to match the site started working fine.

Below is the regional settings

[image]